# cURL error: [77] error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: php, curl

I use paypal IPN class [Quixotix-PHP-PayPal-IPN](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN)
Now, I get notifcation from paypal to my ipn listener,
and i activate the class, but i get the next error:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL error: [77] error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /home/star1231/public_html/cert/api_cert_chain.crt
CApath: none' in /home/star1231/public_html/ipn.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 /home/star1231/public_html/ipn.php(175): IpnListener->curlPost('cmd=_notify-val...')
#1 /home/star1231/public_html/ipn.php(7): IpnListener->processIpn()
#2 {main}
```

I search about this error,

and i read that i need to install ca-certificates package,
in this question: [How do I deal with certificates using cURL while trying to access an HTTPS url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url)

i have no exprince in that staff, and i dont know where to run commands and what i need to download

so someone can please explain me how can i install the package in Cpanel on Godaddy?

Comment: Please clarify your question so we can better assist you. Consider reading the help page at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if someone need the solution ...
First, Download [api_cert_chain.crt](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/blob/master/cert/api_cert_chain.crt)

(if this link dosent work, just search in google "download api_cert_chain.crt" or something like that.)

Second, After you download this file put this file in "cert" Folder where your ipn listener is found.
and you ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

Check out: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/issues/37

> seting $listener->use_curl = FALSE; problem was solved

I am not a PHP dev, and I will be of little help assisting you with Linux, but you should be able to get this working by thoroughly reviewing the answers to these two questions:

1. [Paypal IPN Getting blank confirmation ( should be "VERIFIED" or "INVALID" )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574996/paypal-ipn-getting-blank-confirmation-should-be-verified-or-invalid)
2. [How do I deal with certificates using cURL while trying to access an HTTPS url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url)

The problem appears to be your Certificate Authority bundle, as **meda** writes: (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26260710/399124)

> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). The
>   default bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt ... **If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use the -k (or --insecure) option.**

To verify that that is the problem, I would try is adding the -k or --insecure switch to the code in `Quixotix-PHP-PayPal-IPN` that's failing. Based on the stack trace, that's probably in `/home/star1231/public_html/ipn.php(175)`.

Assuming that fixes it, we now need to figure out what's wrong with the bundle.

Does the file at `/home/star1231/public_html/cert/api_cert_chain.crt` even exist? If not, download it from (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/master/cert/api_cert_chain.crt) and put it in the folder.

If you're still having trouble after you're sure the file is in the right place, you could have a security issue:

> if there is no tls/certs folder: create one and change permissions using chmod 777 -R folderNAME